# Ios6 keyboard shows informal behavior on 'MFMailComposeViewController' and 'MFMessageComposeViewController'

Tags: ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

There is some informal behaviour of native keyboard, some extra space shows below it. However this problem is only in iPhone 5 ios6, not in ios7.

[image]

[image]